# Can you use font ligatures with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm implementing a text editor based on JavaFX. Is it possible to display font ligatures in the same way they work for example in Intellij?

I've found a reference to ligature support in the [JavaFX API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1/docs/api/javafx.scene.text/javafx.scene.text.Font.html), but I don't know if this "proves" that there's support.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Tomas Mikula RichTextFX library.

https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/

You many options here :

1) **`InlineCssTextArea`** uses the

```
Node#setStyle(String cssStyle)
```

method to style Text objects of

```
InlineCssTextArea
```

and for each word or line you can set a different style using :

```
InlineCssTextArea.setStyle(from,to,style);
```

I have extensively used it before to have different fonts and styles inside the same line or lines.

2)  **`StyleClassedTextArea`** uses the `Node#setStyleClass(String styleClass)` method to style `Text` objects. You can define the style classes in your stylesheet.

So let's say that inside your `application.css` you have defined 5 different style classes with different fonts. One of them might be...

```
.red { -fx-fill: red; }
```

so you can use :

```
styleClassedTextArea.setStyleClass(from, to, "red");
```

This renders the text in the range [from, to) in red.

3) For more please check https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX it has detailed description.

Also you can search for more examples on the web.

Comment: I'm actually already using the excellent RichtTextFX and this makes the editor implementation quite easy. Do you know how to make it display font ligatures? See this link for how it displays != as an equals sign with a line across: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: @kossmoboleat I am researching about it . Actually i have used different fonts but never to display font ligatures . I dind't even knew what they are until you asked this question . I will be back when i find the solution :)

Comment: I'm also already using RichTextFX and can confirm in 2021 that Fire Code is not displaying ligatures

Comment: @MattGroth this question has been here a long time and hasn't really been appropriately answered (so it probably won't be now).  I don't know the answer.  Try [asking the JavaFX developers](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX will render required ligatures, but it has no ability to opt in to optional ligatures.  The issue tracking adding an API to enable this behaviour is https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8091616.

See also this message from the OpenJFX dev mailing list: https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2022-October/036309.html